# Twig/Symfony2 : multiples roles with is_granted

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1

I want to know if a user has the 'VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA' role, but I have a problem using the twig function `is_granted()`.

If I use in a template :

```
Roles : {{ dump(app.user.getRoles()) }}
is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') : {{ dump(is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')) }}
is_granted('VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA') : {{ dump(is_granted('VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA')) }}
```

This is what I get when rendering  :

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(16) "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
  [1]=>
  string(16) "VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA"
}
is_granted('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN') : bool(true)
is_granted('VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA') : bool(false)
```

I've tried to logging in and out, emptying symfony's cache.
I also tried to switch the order of roles in the array returned by the method getRoles() of my User : the function is_granted will only take into account the first role of the array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I ended up creating a new method `hasRole` in my `User` Class :

```
public function hasRole($role)
{
    return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());
}
```

Then, in a template, I use:

```
{% if app.user.hasRole('ROLE_VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA') %}
    {# do something #}
{% endif %}
```

---

**EDIT:**
As @JonnyS said, it may be possible that roles must start with `ROLE_` to work with `is_granted` Symfony's function. Didn't tested.

Comment: as a matter of clarity maybe directly return the result of in_array, rather than adding a if/else: `return in_array($role, $this->getRoles());`

Comment: It's not the same thing is_granted accounts for ROLE inheritance, while just checking if user has a specified role does not

Answer (score 9):

If you are expecting Symfony2 to handle your roles, then your roles need to start with "ROLE_".

Change

```
'VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA'
```

to

```
'ROLE_VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA'
```

Of course, you'll need to change this in your config and add the new role.

This answer does not apply, if you are using a dedicated Role class.

Comment: I'm not using a Role class, this is my definition of getRoles() :

`public function getRoles()
{
if($this->role == 100) return array('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN', 'VIEW_GEOLOC_DATA');
}`

But the behaviour is the same as [Managing Roles in the Database](http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database)

Comment: Try changing it over to use the 'ROLE_' prefix.  Symfony 2 doesn't like roles without the prefix.  From the docs, "All roles must begin with the ROLE_ prefix to be managed by Symfony2."  http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/book/security.html  Good Luck and let me know if it works.

Comment: @JonnyS: I was running in to the same problem as the OP. You are correct that the role names must begin with ROLE_. At first it still didn't work, but when I logged out and then back in then the is_granted method started working for checking against roles that begin with ROLE_.

Comment: @DavidBaucum : I've just tested under Symfony 2.4.2 and, indeed, it works. But I'm pretty sure that under 2.1 it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Security Voter that checks this.
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters_data_permission.html

This is much cleaner then creating an method on an entity for this.